# Java image icon array

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

How can I make an array of image icons? When I click a `JButton` on a different class, the `ImageIcon`s should be set to a `JLabel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ImageIcon[] array` and when clicking the button: `label.setIcon(array[i])` in the `actionPerformed` method of the corresponding `ActionListener`.

Comment: Thankyou. Thomas the [] can have a number in it?

Comment: 1. You could do `ImageIcon[] array = new ImageIcon[10];` for an array of 10 `ImageIcon` instances, just like any other array (note that you'd still need to initialize the array elements). 2. You should be able to use that approach in what you pasted. In that case, however, I'd suggest to use a `Map<card, ImageIcon>` instead of an array in order to make looking up the correct `ImageIcon` easier (however, you could also use `D_A.ordinal()`, for example).

Comment: Thanks Thomas Ive tried doing this how ever i am unsure how to initialise. http://pastebin.com/w935XcA6

Comment: Well, you already initialize the first element: `ImageIcon[0] array = new ImageIcon("6.png");` Just do the same for the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Also consider this alternate implementation of [`Card`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html).